# Encapsulating ajax call fails probably because of object visibility 

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this piece of code that is supposed to work on Firefox 3.6 . The problem is that the variable this.xmlhttp that should be defined to STEP2 and used on STEP3 acts as if the code on STEP2 and STEP3 is on different variable environments even though I expect the 2 usages in server_request and callback_function to point to the same member object in the query_request_manager superobject defined lower . I have also created similar code without asynchronous callback at the time of server response that works as I intend it to work .

```
function Generic_server_request(server_location, server_file, client_callback_function)
{
    this.server_location = server_location;
    this.server_file = server_file;
    this.query_parameters = "";
    this.client_callback_function = client_callback_function;
    this.xmlhttp = undefined;
} // STEP1 should create xmlhttp as undefined

Generic_server_request.prototype.callback_function = function ()
{
    if (this.xmlhttp.readyState === 4 // STEP3 ERROR this.xmlhttp is undefined
    // I expected it to be the object defined at STEP2
    // but it's not so according to firebug
    // similar code without asynchronous callback
    // seems to work as I expect it to : no undefined error
    && this.xmlhttp.status === 200)
    {
        this.client_callback_function(
        this.xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    else if (this.xmlhttp.status !== 200 || (this.xmlhttp.status === 200 && this.xmlhttp.readyState !== 2 && this.xmlhttp.readyState !== 3))
    {
        alert("readystate " + this.xmlhttp.readyState + " status " + this.xmlhttp.status);
    }
};

Generic_server_request.prototype.server_request = function ()
{
    this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // STEP2 xmlhttp defined for use
    this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = this.callback_function; // server callback to prototype.callback
    this.xmlhttp.open("GET", this.server_location + this.server_file + this.query_parameters, true);
    this.xmlhttp.send();
};

Generic_server_request.prototype.set_query_parameters = function (query_parameters)
{
    this.query_parameters = query_parameters;
};

var query_request_manager;

function do_querry()
{
    server_querry("test");
}

function server_querry(input)
{
    if (query_request_manager === undefined)
    {
        query_request_manager = new Generic_server_request( // the definition
        "http://localhost/cgi-bin/", "querry_handler.php", status_text);
    }
    query_request_manager.set_query_parameters("?input=" + input);
    query_request_manager.server_request();
} // the usage

//end javascript

<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="do_querry();" />
```

Comment: Formatting your code and extracting the important parts will help a lot here.

Comment: How about loosing the context of the error in that case ? Besides this code is quite well formated if you have really go about actually trying to see what happens .

Comment: @branco: Careful with loose contexts now. They aren't very *tighly* coupled ;)

Comment: I agree with Ryan...the code should be boiled down further to only the needed parts. You will get quicker replies that way and in the process of boiling down the code, you might figure out the issue yourself as well.

Comment: Thanks alot for changing lisp/python formatting to "proper" javascript/java formatting . That should help people find the answer to my actual problem .

Comment: I found a web page that might hold the answer to my problem , though it needs some deep investigation . http://www.justindeltener.com/maintaining-caller-context-when-using-javascript-class-instance-member-functions-as-ajax-event-handlers/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this assignment:

```
this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = this.callback_function;
```

is assigning the function defined by this.callback_function to onreadystatechange, but is not binding its scope to your query_request_manager (meaning this will be bound to the global scope when the callback is executed, rather than the object you want).  To remedy this, you can use a delegate function:

```
this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (function () {
    var me = this;
    return function () {
       return me.callback_function.apply(me, arguments);
    }
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Generic_server_request = function(server_location, server_file, client_callback_function){
  this.server_location = server_location;
  this.server_file = server_file;
  this.query_parameters = "";
  this.client_callback_function = client_callback_function;
  this.xmlhttp = undefined; // STEP1 should create xmlhttp as undefined
}

Generic_server_request.prototype.callback_function = function(){
  if(this.xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && this.xmlhttp.status === 200){ // STEP3 ERROR this.xmlhttp is undefined
    // I expected it to be the object defined at STEP2
    // but it's not so according to firebug
    // similar code without asynchronous callback
    // seems to work as I expect it to : no undefined error
    this.client_callback_function(this.xmlhttp.responseText);
  } else if(this.xmlhttp.status!==200 || (this.xmlhttp.status===200 && this.xmlhttp.readyState!==2 && this.xmlhttp.readyState!==3)){
    alert("readystate " + this.xmlhttp.readyState + " status " + this.xmlhttp.status);
  }
};
Generic_server_request.prototype.server_request=function(){
  this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // STEP2 xmlhttp defined for use
  this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = this.callback_function; // server callback to prototype.callback
  this.xmlhttp.open("GET", this.server_location + this.server_file + this.query_parameters, true);
  this.xmlhttp.send();
};
Generic_server_request.prototype.set_query_parameters = function(query_parameters){
  this.query_parameters = query_parameters;
};
var query_request_manager; 

function do_querry(){
  server_querry("test");
}
function server_querry(input){
  if(query_request_manager === undefined){
    query_request_manager = new Generic_server_request("http://localhost/cgi-bin/", "querry_handler.php", status_text);
  }
  query_request_manager.set_query_parameters("?input=" + input);
  query_request_manager.server_request();
}


<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="do_querry();" />
```

Comment: Nope . Doesn't work . Though I noticed only one change from function Generic_server_request to var Generic_server_request=function at the top .

Comment: yeah, it's not defined due to scoping, was hoping that would fix it...could try doing var self=this at the top of each function replacing 'this' with self throughout your functions...it's losing scope somewhere.